# Google Cloud Storage Folders with many small KMZ files time-out in upload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, upload

I am fairly new at using this.

I have created a superoverlay in Google Earth on a KMZ.
I want to put those SOL files (small KMZ's) onto the cloud storage so the KMZ can "pull" them as needed without sticking them internal or with the KMZ that will be emailed to some people.

When I have a folder that I need to upload into GCP (or create the folder and upload a bunch of files,) it almost always times-out. "Aw Snap!", or it gives me a "wait or exit page" error.

Internet seems stable and strong.  I have tried many ways.  Can't use the service with thisproblem.

FWIW I am on Linux Manjaro using several browsers but mostly Chrome.

Any suggestions for doing these types of uploads?

Comment: How are you uploading files? Are you using the Cloud Console? And, the "Aw Snap" is from a Chrome tab crashing, right? You said "mostly" Chrome - do other browsers crash too?

Comment: How much is "many files"?

Comment: Many is approximately 5000 to 12000, is as much as I have seen. It always depends on the map size, of course.

Browsers... I have tried this on 2 different machines, (1 WIN-10) and with several different browsers... MS Edge, Vivaldi, etc.

Thanx for the comments. Hope I figure it out. Google has been contacted, but they wanted $500 per month to give me phone support! No.
I am happy to find another option. Considering GeoServer on a NAS right now.

Comment: Sorry Jesse, I missed your comment somehow.
I upload via drag-n-drop or Folder/File uploads, from the browser, in the cloud console.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upload a folder having a large number (6000-12000) of files and faced a ‘wait or exit’ page error. I have raised an issue in Public Issue Tracker which you can track [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197728385). I would recommend you to star the issue so that you will get notified whenever there is any update on the issue.

It is recommended to use gsutil to upload a large amount of files to Google Cloud Storage. I would suggest you go through [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#gsutil) and try uploading the files using gsutil.